# grade table with question/parts/subparts

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, cleveref, exam

I am trying to modify the code I have obtained from [sykora](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103692/generating-gradetables-with-parts-using-the-exam-class/194612#194612) so that, I can add `\question` and `subparts` points to the grade table.

So far I have modified the code as.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{xparse,booktabs,xpatch}

% redefine \part command to be \mypart
\appto\parts{\let\exampart\part\let\part\mypart}
\appto\subparts{\let\examsubpart\part\let\part\mysubpart} %subpart
\appto\question{\let\examquestion\part\let\part\myquestion} %question

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_grade_table_tl% this will; become the new grade table

\int_new:N \g_score_int% this will be the exam score
\NewDocumentCommand\mypart{o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\exampart}{
        % don't do anything special inside solutions
        \if@insolution\exampart[#1]
        \else\exampart[#1]
        \int_compare:nNnT {\arabic{partno}} = {1} {
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_grade_table_tl { \midrule }
        }
        \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_grade_table_tl {
            \arabic{question}\alph{partno}
        }
        \tl_gput_right:No \g_grade_table_tl  {& #1 & \\}
        \int_gadd:Nn \g_score_int {#1}
        \fi
    }
}

% Subpart
\NewDocumentCommand\mysubpart{o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\examsubpart}{
        % don't do anything special inside solutions
        \if@insolution\examsubpart[#1]
        \else\exampart[#1]
        \int_compare:nNnT {\arabic{subpartno}} = {1} {
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_grade_table_tl { \midrule }
        }
        \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_grade_table_tl {
            \arabic{question}\alph{subpartno}
        }
        \tl_gput_right:No \g_grade_table_tl  {& #1 & \\}
        \int_gadd:Nn \g_score_int {#1}
        \fi
    }
}

% question
\NewDocumentCommand\myquestion{o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\examquestion}{
        % don't do anything special inside solutions
        \if@insolution\examquestion[#1]
        \else\examquestion[#1]
        \int_compare:nNnT {\arabic{questionno}} = {1} {
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_grade_table_tl { \midrule }
        }
        \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_grade_table_tl {
            \arabic{question}\alph{questionno}
        }
        \tl_gput_right:No \g_grade_table_tl  {& #1 & \\}
        \int_gadd:Nn \g_score_int {#1}
        \fi
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\GradeTable{}{% the new grade table
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}\toprule Question & Points & Score \\
        \tl_use:N \g_grade_table_tl \midrule
        Total & \int_use:N \g_score_int & \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question[2] This is question 1
        \question What if there were no air?
        \begin{parts}
            \part[4]
            Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
            \part[6]
            Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
        \end{parts}
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \part[12]
            Define the universe.
            Give three examples.
            \part[8]
            If the universe were to end, how would you know?
            \part
            \begin{subparts}
                \subpart[10] Subpart 1
                \subpart[5] Subpart 2
            \end{subparts}
        
                    
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
    
    \GradeTable
    
\end{document}
```

So far this this is what I get:
[image: Result]

What I would like is:

[image: Desired Result]

#### EDIT

I managed to edit the code from another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495534/custom-points-table-for-exam).

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch,etoolbox}



% redefine \question command to be \myquest
\appto\questions{\let\examquestion\question\let\question\myquestion}
% redefine \part command to be \mypart
\appto\parts{\let\exampart\part\let\part\mypart}
% redefine \part command to be \mysubpart
\appto\subparts{\let\examsubpart\subparts\let\subparts\mysubpart}


\def\multiplechoice{10}
\def\freeresponse{0}
\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
% this will become a sequence of the part numbers and scores
% like: 1a,10,1b,8,1c,9,2a,6,2b,8,3,12,4,14, ...
\clist_new:N \g_grades_clist
\clist_new:N \g_grades_aux_clist

\int_new:N \g_row_int
\int_new:N \g_multiple_choice_int
\int_new:N \g_free_response_int
\int_new:N \g_grade_total_int
\int_new:N \g_number_of_scores_int

% add a question/part number and score to \g_grades_clist
\cs_new:Nn \__add_to_grades_list:nn {
  \clist_gput_right:Nx \g_grades_clist { #1 }
  \clist_gput_right:Nx \g_grades_clist { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\myquestion{o}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\examquestion}{
    % don't do anything special inside solutions
    \if@insolution\examquestion[#1]
    \else\examquestion[#1]
      % store both the part number and score in \g_grades_clist
      \__add_to_grades_list:nn { \arabic{question} } { #1 }
    \fi
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\mypart{o}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\exampart}{
    % don't do anything special inside solutions
    \if@insolution\exampnrt[#1]
    \else\exampart[#1]
      % store both the part number and score in \g_grades_clist
      \__add_to_grades_list:nn { \arabic{question}\alph{partno} } { #1 }
    \fi
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\mysubpart{o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\examsubpart}{
        % don't do anything special inside solutions
        \if@insolution\examsubpart[#1]
        \else\examsubpart[#1]
        % store both the part number and score in \g_grades_clist
        \__add_to_grades_list:nn { \arabic{question}\alph{partno}\roman{mysubpart} } { #1 }
        \fi
    }
}
\AtEndDocument{
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout } {
    \token_to_str:N \SetGradeList { \g_grades_clist  } ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \SetMultipleChoice {\multiplechoice} ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \SetFreeResponse   {\freeresponse} ^^J
  }
}
% set grade list, multiple choice and free responses from the aux file
\NewDocumentCommand\SetGradeList{m}{\clist_gset:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\SetMultipleChoice{m}{\int_gset:Nn \g_multiple_choice_int {#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\SetFreeResponse{m}{\int_gset:Nn \g_free_response_int {#1}}
% print row #1 of the part scores in the grade table
\cs_new:Nn \__add_row_to_grade_table: {
     \int_gincr:N \g_row_int
       \clist_item:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {2*\g_row_int-1}
      &\clist_item:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {2*\g_row_int}
       \int_gadd:Nn \g_grade_total_int {\clist_item:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {2*\g_row_int}}
     &&
     \int_compare:nTF {2*\g_row_int+\g_number_of_scores_int <= \clist_count:N \g_grades_aux_clist }{
       \clist_item:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {2*\g_row_int+\g_number_of_scores_int-1}
      &\clist_item:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {2*\g_row_int+\g_number_of_scores_int}
        \int_gadd:Nn \g_grade_total_int {\clist_item:Nn \g_grades_aux_clist {2*\g_row_int+\g_number_of_scores_int}}
     }{&}
     &\\\hline
     \int_compare:nT {\g_row_int < \g_number_of_scores_int/2} { \__add_row_to_grade_table: }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\PrintGradeTable{}{% the new grade table
  % we need an exam number of scores so add two
  % empty cells if we have an odd number
  \int_set:Nn \g_number_of_scores_int {(\clist_count:N \g_grades_aux_clist)/2}
  \int_if_odd:nT {\g_number_of_scores_int} {
      \int_add:Nn \g_number_of_scores_int {1}

  }
  \int_gzero:N \g_row_int % a counter to step through the rows
  \int_add:Nn \g_grade_total_int { \g_multiple_choice_int }
  \int_add:Nn \g_grade_total_int { \g_free_response_int }
  % create the grade table
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline\rowcolor{gray!20}
    Question & Points~Possible & Points~Earned & Question & Points~Possible & Points~Earned \\\hline
    % the number of rows that we need is \g_number_of_scores_int/2
    \int_compare:nT {\g_number_of_scores_int>0} { \__add_row_to_grade_table: }
    \multicolumn2{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{r|}{Multiple~Choice}
        & \int_use:N \g_multiple_choice_int & \\\cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn2{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{r|}{Free~response}
        & \int_use:N \g_free_response_int   & \\\cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn2{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textit{Exam~total}}
        & \int_use:N \g_grade_total_int & \\\cline{3-6}
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \PrintGradeTable

  \begin{questions}
    \question[2] Question 1
    \question
      \begin{parts}
        \part[4]
        \part[6]
      \end{parts}
    \question
      \begin{parts}
          \part[12]
          \part[8]
      \end{parts}
    \question
      \begin{parts}
          \part
          \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[10]
            \subpart[5]
            \end{subparts}
            \end{parts}
  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```